# Zend_Pdf font problems with german language.....?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I am using `Zend_Pdf class` to create a `PDF document`.

Here the contents are in the `GERMAN language`, So when I write the content to the pdf it automatically `converts` those `characters` to `some special chars`.

I am not able to figure out the problem....?

I tried some code like

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

But it is not taking it and `showing the same result`.....!!!!!!

Please provide some code or links that helps me........

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Zsub,

I got the solution using following code :

```
$text = $this->_font->encodeString($text, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably write to a Zend_Pdf_Page using something like

```
$page->drawText($text, $xpos, $ypos);
```

Just add the encoding:

```
$page->drawText($text, $xpos, $ypos, 'UTF-8');
```